# Forms in reactjs with flux

Tags: forms, reactjs, flux

I have a form, this form needs to post some data to my backend. With flux, what is the best practice for doing this, use a store?

My issue with using a store is that I have a sub component inside of my form that allows me to select a number 1-5 with buttons. I wanted that component to be reusable, but if i use a store, I have to hard code the store into the child component which means I cant really  use it elsewhere. Instead do I just set the parent state from the child?

If anyone can point out some good tutorials or examples of react/flux forms let me know.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion any back end interaction should be done by using actions, but...

if you want to use store anyway then you can create additional attribute (prop) in your sub-component which will be a function (f.e. `onChange`) which should be passed from parent component as prop (this function should set data in store). Then you can reuse this component, because only parent needs to have access to store.

So in subcomponent:

```
onButtonClick(e) {
    this.state.value = e.target.value;
    if (this.props.onChange) this.props.onChange(e.target.value);
}


<div>
    <button onClick={this.onButtonClick.bind(this)} value="1">1</button>
    <button onClick={this.onButtonClick.bind(this)} value="2">2</button>
    <button onClick={this.onButtonClick.bind(this)} value="3">3</button>
    <button onClick={this.onButtonClick.bind(this)} value="4">4</button>
    <button onClick={this.onButtonClick.bind(this)} value="5">5</button>
</div>
```

and in parent:

```
setMyStoreState(value) {
    store.setNumber(value);
}

<Subcomponent onChange={this.setStoreState.bind(this)} />
```

or something like this.

Code not tested, but you should get the idea.

Comment: So in your opinion where do I store the form data before firing off an action to post the data?

Comment: In component state

Comment: that makes more sense tome, I just always see people using stores. Thats why i was biased towards that